# Design of "modified" messages suggests that the post was modified by the the wrong user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edit-history, recent-activity

I was browsing through the [recently active questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and I flipped out a little bit when I saw this:

[image: screenshot of old question]

because I recognized [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328423/what-does-8-5070592e37-mean), and although the page seemed to say that I had edited it 19 minutes ago, I did not remember doing so.  I have a poor memory, but it is not usually as poor as that.

When I looked into it, I found that in fact, it was on the "recently active" page and was marked as "modified 19 minutes ago" because *Jonas Meyer* had posted [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328423/what-does-8-5070592e37-mean#comment1092839_328423) on it. I had nothing to do with it.

The positioning of "modified 19 minutes ago" and my infocard seems to attribute the modification to me.  But it wasn't me; it was Jonas.

I think the design should be changed to prevent this reasonable but incorrect inference, or, better, the infocard displayed should be from the person who was *actually* responsible for the presence of the question on the recent activity page.

Comment: Actually, I think it was marked as "recently active" because it was  recently re-opened.   For whatever reason when a question is re-opened even though the time of the most recent activity is updated (to the time of re-opening), there is no "owner" of this activity, and the user who made the most recent edit remains listed.

Comment: Oh, that would make sense then. I had thought that commenting didn't bump a post, and was too quick to revise my belief about that.  I will shortly delete this question.

Comment: I don't think this question should be deleted.  It might prove useful to other people in the future.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Related post at meta.SO: [Reopening attributed to wrong user on front page and question pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132158/reopening-attributed-to-wrong-user-on-front-page-and-question-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthur Fischer suggests that the post was bumped to the "recently active" page not because of Jonas Meyer's comment (comments do not bump posts) but because it had been recently reopened after being closed.

The most recent modification was attributed to me either because I had been last to edit the post (although it was a long time earlier) or, conceivably, because I was the first to vote for reopening.  In any case it is not clear there is a better answer to the question, although I think attributing the modification to "Community", as is sometimes done, might be less confusing.

Martin Sleziak points out that [this question has come up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132158/reopening-attributed-to-wrong-user-on-front-page-and-question-pages).

Thanks to everyone who participated in the discussion.